# Disable automatic code rearrangement in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, version-control, git-commit

After I updated IntelliJ IDEA, it started to rearrange code before each git commit. I found rearrange rules in **Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java** but there is no checkbox for enable/disable feature.
How can I disable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to 
**View | Tool Windows | Version Control - Local Changes tab- Right click the text "*Default*" - Commit Changes** (or Arrow icon on the left hand sided toolbar inside Local Changes tab). Find **Before Commit** section.

[image]

and un-tick **Rearrange code**.

Refer [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/commit-changes-dialog.html#d1556278e237) for more.

Comment: You have to actually commit something in order for the uncheck to be saved. If you click `cancel`, it reverts back to checked.